# Fail to get convergence on point iteration method

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, numerical-optimization

I have the following formula:

$$\lambda = \lambda(1-F(S-2)) + \frac{r}{c}p$$, where $S, p, r$ and $c$ are constants and $F(.)$ is the CDF function of a random (Poisson distributed) variable, so $F(S-2) =\sum_{x=0}^{S-2} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$

I am trying to find $\lambda$ for which the equation holds and I therefore tried the point iteration method.

So I'm deploying the following:

$$\lambda_{n+1} = \frac{\frac{r}{c}p}{F(S-2)}$$, where $$F(S-2) =\sum_{x=0}^{S-2} \frac{e^{-\lambda_n}\lambda_n^x}{x!}$$

But it doesn't seem to converge to a $\lambda$ for which the equation holds...

Anyone an idea why it doesn't converge? Am I doing something wrong? Or could it perhaps be that there is a closed form solution for $\lambda$?

Comment: Fixed point methods don't always converge. Even near a solution, if the derivative is too sharp, fixed point methods can be unstable. Have you tried plotting $\lambda \mapsto \lambda F(S-2)$ to see how it behaves? Newton's method could perhaps be an option.

Comment: @Gribouillis thanks for your comment. I know that F(S−2) behaves smooth, so I would think that convergence was possible.

Answer (score 1):

$$F(s-2) =\sum_{x=0}^{S-2} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}=\frac{\Gamma (s-1,\lambda )}{\Gamma (s-1)}$$ So, what you want is to solve for $\lambda$ the equation
$$\lambda\Gamma (s-1,\lambda )= k \qquad \text{with} \qquad k=\Gamma (s-1) \frac r c p$$ or better, to find the possible zeros of function
$$f(\lambda)=\lambda\Gamma (s-1,\lambda )- k$$
$$f'(\lambda)=\Gamma (s-1,\lambda )-e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^{s-1}$$ and then Newton iterates are
$$\lambda_{n+1}=\frac{\lambda_n  \left(\lambda_n^s-e^{\lambda_n } k\right)}{\lambda_n ^s-e^{\lambda_n }
   \lambda_n  \Gamma (s-1,\lambda_n )}$$ The problem is to find a reasonable $\lambda_0$.